# Strange behavior with CakePHP conventions (2.3.1.) on different servers

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I've created an application on XAMPP packet on Windows 8. It works great.

Now, when I've uploaded it on a server (Linux) there are some problems.

Let's say, "ClientStatus".

```
Controller name: "ClientStatuses".
File name: "ClientStatusesController.php".
Plural: "ClientStatuses".
Singular: "ClientStatus".
```

But on the Linux server, it says that I must have "**ClientstatusesController.php**". Why is that? What I need to change in configuration so the conventions would be the same on XAMPP and Linux server? Is it something in .htaccess?

Any info will be great. Thank you. :)

It's **CakePHP 2.3.1**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that "*nix" are case-sensitive with folder names. It has to be ClientstatusesController.php.

Well, here I want to tell you one more thing I've solved when I've uploaded a project on the server.

For transforming JavaScript array to JSON I've used `JSON.stringify()` and server's `json_decode()` always returned "null" when converting back.

I think it's because of 3 BOM characters. This solved the problem.

```
$table = json_decode(stripslashes($_REQUEST['table']), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The conventions always was "plural" for controllers, therefore there is only one correct name:

```
ClientstatusesController
```

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

or try http://inflector.cakephp.org/clientstatus

Comment: "ClientStatuses" is also plural. Difference is only in "S". And why it works on XAMPP and not on Linux? That's the question. :)

Comment: thats the point. but you said `Controller name: "ClientStatus"` which is wrong.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I meant "ClientStatuses". Thank you.

Comment: Here is +1 for finding a typo. :)